# Variable query parameter names in OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

Does anyone have an ideal how to model that in OpenAPI specification? :-/

> https://api.example.de/search?facet=key1&facet=key2&key1=value1&key2=value2

`key1`, `key2` etc. are given values from an enumeration. It there a way to describe them more detailed?

```
/search:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: facet
          required: false
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              enum:
                - key1 # Description?
                - key2
        - in: query
          name: {facet_name}
          required: false
          ???
```

Is that the only solution:

```
/search:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: facet
          required: false
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              enum:
                - key1 # Description ?
                - key2
        - in: query
          name: key1
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Key1 is that...
```

Comment: did you manage to find any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

All values in an enum must adhere to the specified type. If you need to specify descriptions for enum items, you can do this in the description of the parameter or property,

Description supports Markdown [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/help/) for rich text representation, Like below example:

```yaml
description: >
  **Your Title**:
    * `key1` - description for key1
    * `key2` - description for key2
```

**It will look:**

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! It's better than nothing... ;-) Do you have any ideas about the variable-query-parameter thing?

Comment: @michael, i am not getting, can you share example about `variable-query-parameter`